# Python Warning - Command not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, sublimetext3, macos-catalina

I am very new to using Python and Mac OS. When I run the basic command *x=5* in Sublime Text the statement runs and I'm able to call it. However, in the "log" I see **~/.bash_profile: line 1: 3: command not found**.

This seems to only be an issue when I'm running on the default Python build or with the Python + Virtual Environment build. If I run this on the Python 3.8 build, the issue doesn't appear. I followed the readme file provided by the virtual environment package for setting the virtual environment using python 3, but it didn't seem to have any effect even after restarting Sublime.

Has anyone had this issue or know how to fix it so that the virtual environment will run on python 3? I figure the issue is mainly due to my lack of understanding the package.

Below are my Virtualenv user settings

```
{ 
    // Assuming virtualenv installed on default python prefix.
    // Depending on your setup you might want to change this to something like:
    // "virtualenv", "virtualenv-3.3", "python3 -m virtualenv" ...
    "executable": "python3 -m virtualenv",

    // Directory paths searched for virtualenvs.
    // First one will be used as default destination for new virtualenvs.
    "virtualenv_directories": [
        "~/.virtualenvs",  // virtualenvwrapper $WORKON_HOME
    ],

    // Additonal paths searched for python installations.
    // Portable pythons? Perhaps?
    "extra_paths": []
}
```

Comment: The error message you're citing looks to be complaining about something near the start of your `.bashrc` file; have you checked those lines to see what command it might be trying to execute that it can't find?

Comment: do I check that with nano ~/.bashrc ? If so, nothing is in there

Comment: found it...I guess I saved a random 3 in my bash_profile at some point. Thanks!